# Not sure about my reasoning in this exercise (standard deviation)

Tags: probability, standard-deviation, means

I was given this exercise:

[image]

I did this but i am not sure if my reasoning or even my answer is okay.

```
Given cheeses (weight in Kg)X with N(10,2^2)
u = 10, σ = 2

more than 9 kg, paid $20
less than 9 kg, lost $5
```

$$P (x > g) = P ({\frac{(x - 10)}{2} > \frac{(g - 10)}{2}})$$

$$= P( Z > -0.5) = 1 - P(Z <= -0.5)$$
$$= 1 - P(Z <= -0.5)$$
$$= 1 - [1 - P(Z <= -0.5)]$$
$$= P(Z < 0.5)$$

---

$$P(x <= g) = P(\frac{(x - 10)}{2} <= \frac{(g - 10)}{2})$$

$$=P(Z <= -0.5)$$

$$=1 - P (Z < 0.5)$$

---

$$P(x > h) >= 0.991$$

$$P({\frac{(x - 10)}{1}} > \frac{(h - 10)}{2}) >= 0.991$$

$$P(Z > \frac{(h -10)}{2}) >= 0.991$$

$$(h - 10)/2 = 2.37$$

$$h = 4.74 + 10$$

so, the answer should be 14 cheeses.

Am i right?

Comment: There must be at least 2250 cheeses in order to get the required value (45000 dollar).

Comment: What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You must first calculate the probability that a cheese is good (> 9 kilo) or bad. These are numbers ! Then you get to step 2. If you have N cheeses, what is the expected value of the set and what is the standard deviation in that value? You can then examine how the required criteria for the set can be met.

Answer (score 1):

We first determine the probability $p$ that a cheese is good (weight > $9$ kilo). Now the standard deviation is $2$ kilo, and a cheese $1$ kilo lighter than the mean ($10$ kilo) is not good. A table with normal distribution values tells us for $z = -0.5$ that $p = 0.6915$.

Next we derive expressions for the average value $A$ (in dollars) of one cheese; and for the standard deviation $\sigma$ in the value (in dollars) of one a cheese:

$$A = p * 20 + (1-p) * -5 = 12.2875$$

$$\sigma = (20 + 5) * \sqrt {p(1-p)} = 11.5469$$

Now the question is how many cheeses must be produced to guarantee a total value of $45000$ dollar with a probability of at least $0.991$. Using a table with normal distribution values we see that the probabilty of $0.991$ corresponds with a $z$ value of $-2,37$.

The equation for the required value $V$ of $N$ cheeses at a $0.991$ confidence level thus becomes:

$$V = A * N - 2.37 * \sigma * \sqrt{N} > 45000$$

This is a quadratic equation in $N$, or rather in $\sqrt{N}$, that can be solved by standard methods. The result is $N = 3800$. Had we asked for the number of cheeses to yield an average value of $45000$ dollar, the result would have been $N = 3663$. Hence the effect of fluctuations on the required number of cheeses is fairly small.